# Finding a limit involving Fourier series and Dirichlet's kernel

Tags: calculus, limits, fourier-series, convolution

> Find the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^{2\pi} (x+\frac{\pi}{2})^2 \frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})x + x\cos nx}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\ dx$$

So we may define $f = (x+\frac{\pi}{2})^2$ and then look at the convolution:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}(x+\frac{\pi}{2})^2 \frac{\sin((n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin\frac{x}{2}}\ dx = 2\pi f\star D_n$$ where $D_n$ is [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel)

Now, we know that $f\star D_n = S_N(f, x)$, the partial sum of the Fourier series of $f(x)$.

So basically at this point I considered evaluating the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ but it got relatively complicated so I guess I should take another approach.

As for the other part of the integral, I think we may look at $$g(x)=\frac{(x+\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

And from Riemann–Lebesgue lemma we have that: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{2\pi} g(x)\cos nx = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right. In your equation for the convolution, the expression on the left is a number and the expression on the right is a function. Let's fix this: Set $h(x) = (\pi/2-x)^2.$ Then your integral equals

$$\int_0^{2\pi}h(0-x) D_n(x)\,dx  = 2\pi h * D_n (0).$$

So that makes sense, but I don't really see how to use this here. Note that as a $2\pi$-periodic function, $h$ has a jump discontinuity at $0 \sim 2\pi.$

Why not just do the following:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}(x+\pi/2)^2 D_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^{2\pi}[x^2 + x\pi + (\pi^2/4)] D_n(x)\,dx.$$

Now $D_n(x) = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}e^{ikx}.$ The integrals $\int_0^{2\pi}xe^{ikx}\,dx, \int_0^{2\pi}x^2e^{ikx}\,dx$ don't look that bad to me, and of course integrating $D_n$ against a constant is easy.

Comment: I found the solution; We know that $h\star D_n(x)=S_n(h,x)$. And since $h$ is Lipschitz then by Dirichlet's theorem $S_n(h, x)\to h(x)$ (point-wise).

Comment: so we left with $g(x)=\frac{(x+\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}}$. I don't think Riemann–Lebesgue could be applied here since $g(x)$ isn't $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: I meant $g(x)=x\frac{(x+\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{\sin\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Comment: You want $\sin x/2$ downstairs. You can't apply Dirichlet that way as $h$ is not a $2\pi$ periodic Lipschitz function - it has a jump discontinuity at  $0\sim 2\pi.$ Riemann Lebesgue works fine on $g;$ that's the easy part of the problem.